Why nginx proxy_pass dont get shoutcast page and get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS?
location / {

    set $stream_username $host;   
    if ($host ~* "^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\.test\.example\.com$") {
        set $stream_username $1;
    }
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2198/proxy-redirect/$stream_username;
    proxy_set_header X-MountPoint $uri;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 8;
    proxy_read_timeout 15;
    proxy_send_timeout 15;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
}


location ~ ^/streamproxy/(.*)$ {
        internal;

        set $stream_url http://$1;

        proxy_buffering                 off;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort       off;
        proxy_intercept_errors          off;
        proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header;
        proxy_redirect                  off;
        proxy_set_header                User-Agent "$http_user_agent [ip:$remote_addr]";
        proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout           8;
        proxy_send_timeout              60;
        proxy_read_timeout              60;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size        0;
        proxy_pass                      $stream_url$is_args$args;
}


curl -i http://127.0.0.1:2198/proxy-redirect/webradio


HTTP/1.0 200 OK


Content-Length: 8


Connection: close


X-Accel-Buffering: no


X-Accel-Expires: off


X-Accel-Redirect: /streamproxy/ip:port

when you enter the shoutcast page, that is, your ip:port, shoutcast comes up first, that is, ip:port/index.html?sid=1, so if the proxy_pass is http://127.0.0.1:2198/proxy-redirect/$stream_username; which when executed call X-Accel-Redirect and brings the radio's ip:port, if the proxy pass reads the ip:port correctly, the shoutcast page comes up first, http://webradio.test.example.com/index.html?sid=1, but it does not appear because the browser says ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and the shoutcast page does not appear correctly, while when the radio is icecast, the page appears correctly in the browser without any errors. Why ?
Update
location ~ ^/streamproxy/(.*)$ {
    internal;

    set $stream_url http://$1;

    proxy_buffering                 off;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort       off;
    proxy_intercept_errors          on; # Enable error interception
    proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header;
    proxy_redirect                  off; # Disable proxy auto-redirect handling
    proxy_set_header                User-Agent "$http_user_agent [ip:$remote_addr]";
    proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header                Host $host; # Ensure correct Host header
    proxy_connect_timeout           8;
    proxy_send_timeout              60;
    proxy_read_timeout              60;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size        0;
    
    proxy_pass                      $stream_url$is_args$args;
    rewrite / /index.html?sid=1 break;

}

i put under the proxy_pass this "rewrite / /index.html?sid=1 break;"
it works correctly but its not true because shoutcast redirect automaticaly on /index.html?sid=1 and if i put on browser /index.html?sid=2, sid=3 and etc dont work because browser only reads /index.html?sid=1. can anyone help me for this ? Thanks

You cannot use if in a location block to set a variable. If you need to extract part of the hostname, use a regular expression server_name statement.
